# Unable to display column headings for my WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have the following WebGrid and just dont get why my column headings are not showing. I have followed online tutorials and they look identical to the following:

```
 @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "gridhead",
    rowStyle: "gridRow",
    alternatingRowStyle: "gridRow",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("Title","Title",format: @<text>@item.title</text>, style: "Title")
))
```

My CSS:

```
.grid
{
left:30px;
border-collapse:collapse;
color:Black;  
}

.gridhead
{
display:none;
background-color:Aqua;
}
```

When i run my code all i can see are the titles of films but no heading, not even the background colour.

Edit:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "gridhead",
    rowStyle: "gridRow",
    alternatingRowStyle: "gridRow",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("Title","Title",format: @<text>@item.title</text>, style: "Title"),
    grid.Column("Rating","Rating",format: @<text>@item.rating</text>, style: "Rating")
))
```

My CSS:

```
.grid
{
left:30px;
border-collapse:collapse;
color:Black;  
}

.gridhead
{
display:block;
background-color:Aqua;
}
```

Comment: Maybe change the dispaly in `.gridhead` to `display:block;`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `display:none;` from the following css role:

```
.gridhead
{
   display:none;
   background-color:Aqua;
}
```

Make it `display: block;`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I think the styling has affected my other columns though. I can see the title heading and title. I can also see me other column heading:rating, but not the data, but i can when i remove display:block. See edit above for coding